# Google App Engine does not work with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, codeship

I'm trying to deploy my WP application through Codeship. Everything is ok until this part:

```
Step #1: Step 8/8 : RUN /bin/bash /build-scripts/lockdown.sh
Step #1:  ---> Running in ca67ff29436f
Step #1: chown: cannot access '/app/web': No such file or directory
Step #1: Locking down the document root...
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/bash /build-scripts/lockdown.sh'
returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #1
```

It's my first time deploying a WP to GAE and I need help.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just got wordpress up and running on GAE this morning by following these instructions:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/php72/wordpress

(And this is the page that took me there: https://cloud.google.com/wordpress/)

However, I'm not familiar with Codeship. May be try deploying to app engine directly first via Google's instructions? It's possible there are other warnings or errors that codeship is not back to you.

If following google's instructions does work, then maybe transform them into a custom Codeship script https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/continuous-deployment/deployment-with-custom-scripts/